# How do I update NSDictionary in custom Parse class?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

I have a updated NSDictionary created within the application, and I need to update the Parse column in a custom class, `Animal`.

The column is called `AnimalDiet` and is an array of NSDictionaries, and I need to add it to the current user.

Below is my attempt at this, but it attempts to save in the user class.

```
var update = PFUser.currentUser() //How do I specify the class?

    for(var i = 0; i < animal.count; i++){
        animaldiet = ([
            "food":"Food",
            "beverage":"Water"
            ] as? NSDictionary)!
        update.addObject(animaldiet, forKey: "AnimalDiet")
        update.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (true: Bool, error: NSError?) in
            print("\(error)")
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initializing a PFUser, initialize a PFObject.

```
var update = PFObject(className: "Animal")
```

Then to save the user to your animal class you would do (assuming the name of your column is "user"):

```
update.setObject(PFUser.currentUser(), forKey: "user")
```

Comment: But then how do I update the column of a specific user?

Comment: Is the column on your user class or your animal class?

Comment: Yes there is a column in the animal class which is a pointer to the user class

Comment: Where is the animalDiet column?

Comment: In the custom Animal class

Comment: Then you would update the animal object. If you need to then make a relationship between an Animal and a User then that's a different question

Comment: How would I update the animal object of a SPECIFIC user?

Comment: If there is a column in the animal class that is a pointer to the user class, then you would update the user of a SPECIFIC animal since you have a one-to-many relationship between user and animal. If you had a column on your animal class that was a pointer to your user class then your question would make sense. Semantics aside, I will update my answer to show how you would save the user in the column on your Animal.

Comment: I think you are getting a little confused about what I am trying to do. So in the animal class I have animal diet which is an array of nsdictionary and a column which is a pointer to the user. When ever the animal driet for the current user is changed on the app I need to update it on parse. So In the animal class I need to find the current user object in the column which is a pointer to the user class now that I have the current user column in the custom class I need to replace the updated array with the old array in the animal diet column of the current user only